# Ubuntu 18:04: How do I add an application to the list of default applications?

Tags: 18.04, default-programs

I want to install a default handler for MIDI files (such as those embedded in a Wikipedia page such as this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninth_chord). I tried installing two (timidity and Yoshimi). Both are able to play MIDI files from the command line or the application's menu. However, neither of these appear in the list of default applications.

I tried adding a .desktop file (which appears to have worked for previous versions), however it didn't work (also, timidity doesn't have a GUI).

How do I add an application to the list of default applications that pop up? Thanks for any info.

s1b

Edit: My .desktop file looks like this:

```
MimeType=audio/midi;audio/x-mod;
Exec=/usr/bin/timidity -ia %F
```

The same file of two lines is available in the following two locations:

~/.local/share/applications/timidity.desktop

/usr//share/applications/timidity.desktop

Comment: It should be sufficient to have a valid .desktop file in .local/share/applications. Then, the program will show up under "Other applications" in the Properties dialog, Open with tab of the file in Nautilus.

Comment: Thanks, but I did try the .desktop file in /usr/share/applications and ./local/share/applications. Neither of these worked for me.

Comment: Post your desktop file (in your answer - use Edit)

Answer (score 0):

timidity has some kinda pseudo guis. From help

```
 timidity -h
Available interfaces (-i, --interface option):
  -in          ncurses interface
  -ie          Emacs interface (invoked from `M-x timidity')
  -ia          XAW interface
  -id          dumb interface
  -iA          ALSA sequencer interface
```

[image: timidity with gui]

```
MimeType=audio/midi;audio/x-mod;
Exec=/usr/bin/timidity -ia %F
```

And I can play this midi files from your linked side as well.

Comment: While you provide useful information, you do not answer the specific question. Please indicate how the OP can make this the default action for midi files.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work after this step.

Answer (score 0):

To add any program in the list of default list of "open with applications", open a terminal and use the following command:

sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/timidity.desktop

Look for a line that looks like this:

Exec=timidity

and replace it with this:

Exec=timidity %F