# can't encrypt files with cinnamon nemo file manager

Tags: 20.04, encryption, cinnamon, nemo

I upgraded succesfully my Ubuntu 18.04 default amd64 distribution to Ubuntu 20.04 amd64.
On both Ubuntu 18.04  and Ubuntu 20.04 I was able to encrypt files with gpg from the default files filemanager program.
Yesterday I additionaly installed cinnamon on my Ubuntu 20.04.
After installation of cinnamon and reboot of my machine I was only able to decrypt encrypted files with Nemo (default filemanager of cinnamon). I was not able to encrypt new files with Nemo, because Nemo has only a decrypt mouse option and not an encrypt option (both option are available in files filemanager programma of gnome). Now, I can only encrypt files from the commandline with the command:

```
gpg -c <filename>
```

**What do I have to do to add an encrypt option to Nemo?**

Comment: Asked/answered many times before. Check out one of the posts, for example:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199110/ubuntu-1804-how-do-i-add-an-application-to-the-list-of-default-applications/1199127#1199127

Comment: I created in /usr/share/nemo/actions a file encrypt.nemo_action. But that did not work.

Comment: I also placed the file in ~/.local/share/nemo/actions without success.

Comment: I also read https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nemo. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might have a better chance of getting this resolved in Linux Mint forums -- the distro for which cinnamon was written.

Comment: At this moment and for this problem Linux Mint forums does not help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [howto to build nemo extension nemo-seahorse version 4.4.0 without libgnome-keyring-dev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310251/howto-to-build-nemo-extension-nemo-seahorse-version-4-4-0-without-libgnome-keyri)

Answer (score 0):

See issue [howto to build nemo extension nemo-seahorse version 4.4.0 without libgnome-keyring-dev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310251/howto-to-build-nemo-extension-nemo-seahorse-version-4-4-0-without-libgnome-keyri)
When you follow the steps in the link to install the latest cinnamon desktop and install the nemo-seahorse package you can encrypt and decrypt files from nemo filemanager.
The problem is now solved.

Comment: The original question could maybe then be flagged as duplicate?