# howto to build nemo extension nemo-seahorse version 4.4.0 without libgnome-keyring-dev

Tags: 20.04, compiling, cinnamon

I use Ubuntu 20.04 desktop and install afterwards a Cinnamon deskstop.
Because Cinnamon Nemo filemanager did default not have nemo-seahorse support, I want to
build nemo-seahorse extension for Nemo filemanager. I already downloaded nemo-extensions version 4.4.0 from. How can I build nemo-seahorse extension from 4.4.0 source without Ubuntu package libgnome-keyring-dev because it is not provided anymore with ubuntu 20.04, but to build nemo-seahorse extension 4.4.0 from source needs libgnome-keyring-dev because of the build dependancy?

Answer (score 2):

You can save time by using binary pre-compiled packages from 
[“Wasta-Linux” team's Cinnamon-Testing PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewasta-linux/+archive/ubuntu/cinnamon-testing?field.series_filter=focal):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wasta-linux/cinnamon-testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo-seahorse
```

Then restart Nemo by `nemo -q`.

---

Notes:

1. the above PPA has many packages from/for Cinnamon as it shipped in [Wasta Linux](http://www.wastalinux.org/), so you can install fully-featured Cinnamon desktop on your Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system.
2. to revert to default versions you have to remove the PPA use `ppa-purge` - `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge; sudo ppa-purge ppa:wasta-linux/cinnamon-testing` .

Comment: I just tested and it works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user2588998 great, so you can accept my answer to mark problem solved.